# Are there any soultion to stream flv/f4v to Adobe Flash Media Server from files on a client machine?

Tags: streaming, flash, media, adobe

Our customer is looking for a solution to stream flash video to Adobe Flash Media server from his client machine. I need something like Adobe Live Media Encoder, but the source needs to be a playlist on the client machine. I tried Adobe Media Encoder CS4 but it works only with ftp. Are there any good solutions to achieve this ? Any suggestions welcome.

Thx in advance.

ps. Sorry for my poor English :p

Answer (score 1):

FMS 3.0 and 3.5 come with a sample application that streams a webcam from a client PC to the FMS and then distributes it to other clients.

Would it be possible to write a Flash application that does a similar task?

Just to clarify, you want to stream FLV files from Client PC -> FMS?

Comment: I want something like that, but the source has to be a playlist which can be administered on the customers client machine. He has an encoder machine that would push a stream (from files) to the FMS server which distributes it to the clients watching it.